# Internet Explorer 10 immediately closes after opening

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I decided on a whim to give IE10 a try. I'm not terribly sad to lose all access to IE, however I would like to get it working.

As soon as I hit the shortcut it opens and then immediately closes.

1. doesn't work in safe mode
2. Reset IE settings as suggested by MS KB article
3. Reinstalled IE as suggested by MS KB article
4. Re-registered various DLLs
5. Disabled all add-ons
6. Ran in addon disabled mode

What's next?

Comment: I forgot to mention i'm using windows 7 64bit

Comment: Where is the link itself, e.g., pinned to taskbar, on Desktop, pinned to Start Menu, in Start Menu tree? To which directory does the link point: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" or "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" Does right-click Start InPrivate Browsing work?

Comment: Does uninstalling IE10 enable you to run IE9 again as before?

Comment: I suggest changing the start page to `about:blank`. Might or might not help.

Comment: @Karan The Home page can be accessed in Internet Options through Control Panel without opening IE.

Comment: @ryanttb: Ugh, yes, this is IE after all. Been a while since I had to use it, not that I'm complaining!

Comment: Karan - nope i'm stick w/ 10 now.   Ryanttb - Ran from command line as well as shortcut, and also direct dbl click of exe
As i mentioned.. i nuked the IE settings and it did not help

Comment: also inprivate doesn't help...

Comment: FYI.. I nuked and reinstalled to factory spec from disc image. After hours of loading updates IE10 (now 11) installed

Answer (score 0):

have you tried either of the following:

- Revert IE to an older version and then upgrade again
- run sfc /scannow

These seem to be the top 2 solutions I can find on technet: